# Querying FAST Search Server for Sharepoint from Search Webparts

Tags: web-part, search, fast-search, fast-for-sharepoint, fast-esp

I'm new to SharePoint and FAST.

In SharePoint 2007 implementation for our projects we used "Esp-Searchapi" for querying the back-end FAST ESP 5.3.

As we are now migrating to SharePoint 2010 and FAST Search for SharePoint (FS4S), I'll be creating WebParts or use existing one, but the existing API code will no longer work.

I need some references which will provide me a good jump start for querying FS4S back-end search and get the search results.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default you can use the standard web parts. You don't say anything of any particular search needs so hard say where you should start to look. MSDN has samples on overriding the Core Result Web Part, or take a look at the code in spsearchparts.codeplex.com in order to do FQL queries via a web part.

You should look into the following:

- Override Core Result Web Part
- KeywordQuery class

Comment: Thanks Mikael. I'll check these out. One more question. Does your "spsearchparts" project is SP2010 version for ESPWebParts :) Can I use this instead of ESPWebParts ?

Comment: My project is for use with FAST Search for SharePoint. The other project is for ESP 5.3. If you are still using FAST ESP, then you're stuck with the web parts you are using or have to create your own.